# WebSocket connection failed for host: wss://relay.walletconnect.com

Tags: walletconnect, wagmi

My project is using wagmi and walletconnect. But I got this error: WebSocket connection failed for host: wss://relay.walletconnect.com. How can I reproduce this and how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.